# Recaptcha rails verification failed issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, recaptcha

I need to use google reCAPTCHA v2
I have already registered new key and it's domains on localhost and and on heroku on https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin. 
I have recaptcha gem in my **Gemfile**

```
gem 'recaptcha', require: 'recaptcha/rails'
```

In **.env** file I add site key and secret key:

```
RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxXXXXXXXxxxxxxxxXxxxxxxxxxxxx
RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY=xxxxxxxxxXXXxxxxxxXXXXxxxxxxXXxxXxxxxxxx
```

In **/config/initializers/recaptcha.rb** I have:

```
Recaptcha.configure do |config|
  config.site_key  = ENV['RECAPTCHA_SITE_KEY']
  config.secret_key = ENV['RECAPTCHA_SECRET_KEY']
end
```

In my Devise session controller controller I use recaptcha to verify user Sign_in if user made 3 wrong email/pwd attemption to sign_in
I have in **/app/controllers/users/sessions_controller.rb**:

```
class Users::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
  before_action :recaptcha_check, only: :create

  def create
    super
  end

  private

  def recaptcha_check
    cookies[:login_attempts] ||= 0
    cookies[:login_attempts] = cookies[:login_attempts].to_i + 1
    return unless cookies[:login_attempts].to_i > 3
    unless verify_recaptcha
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_back fallback_location: root_path }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
end
```

At first time, when I try it it was OK.
But on the next day and till now it doesn't work.
Every time I have green check mark in recaptcha check_box and click Sign_in I get:

> reCAPTCHA verification failed, please try again.

I tried to update keys 2 or 3 times but it didn't help. Also I tried it on localhost and on heroku. Please let me know what is the reason of this issue and how to fix it.

> **UPDATE 1**

As razvans told me I tried to use verify_recaptcha same as it is in doc of gem. I made something like this:

```
def recaptcha_check
    cookies[:login_attempts] ||= 0
    cookies[:login_attempts] = cookies[:login_attempts].to_i + 1
    return unless cookies[:login_attempts].to_i > 3
    @user = User.new(email: params[:user][:email], password: params[:user][:password], password_confirmation: params[:user][:password])
    unless verify_recaptcha(model: @user)
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_back fallback_location: root_path }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end
```

But this just removed error message. And I think it is because in verify_recaptcha option `:model   Model to set errors` and it just don't show error messages. But verify_recaptcha is still not pass.
Also as I told, I use Devise to authenticate users. And I found here https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/how-to:-use-recaptcha-with-devise the solution for devise with recaptcha, but it is nearly as my code. So I still have this issue and ask for help, please.

Comment: Are you using https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha?  I see the examples with `verify_recaptcha(model: @user)`.

Comment: @razvans I update my question with your comment.

Comment: Then it means the keys are not correct. Try to have them plain in Recaptcha.configure without the .env file.